# I have a repeating result in a column, even though I have rules set against it. How can I remove this repeated occurance?

Tags: windows, pascal, freepascal

The Program problem is this:

**Friendly Numbers**:

There are certain pairs of numbers that are known as 'friendly numbers'. By definition, friendly numbers are two distinct numbers, the sum of whose proper divisors equals the other number.

For example: The smallest pair of friendly numbers are 220 and 284.  The proper divisors of 220 are: 1,2,4,5,10,11,20,22,24,44,55, and 110. The sum of these divisors is 284.

On the other hand, the proper divisors of 284 are: 1,2,4,71, and 142.  The sum of these divisors is 220.

Therefore, 220 and 284 are called 'friendly numbers'.  Write a program to find and print the first two dozen pair of friendly numbers.

The list of friendly numbers can be found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=72239&messageID=319474). I am trying to get to 80620 and 389924.

My source code is here:

```
program  Friendly Numbers;

type List=Array[1..50] of Integer;

var Num,Sum,Sum2,C,C2,C3,C4,CheckNum,LastNum:Integer;
    NumUsed:String;
    CheckedNum,CheckedSum:List;
    
begin
Num:=200;

while C3<=23 Do
  begin
          
    while C<Num Do
      begin  
        C:=C+1;
        if (C<>Num) and (Num mod C=0) then Sum:=Sum+C;
      end;
  
    while C2<Sum Do
      begin
        C2:=C2+1;
        if (C2<>Sum) and (Sum mod C2=0) then Sum2:=Sum2+C2;
      end;

    if Num=Sum2 then
      begin
      
        for C4:=1 to 35 do
          begin
            if CheckedNum[C4]=C2 then NumUsed:='T';
            if CheckedSum[C4]=Num then NumUsed:='T';
          end;
          
        if (C2<>LastNum) and (NumUsed<>'T') and (Num<>C2) then
          begin
            C3:=C3+1;
            Writeln(C3,')',Num:8,C2:8);
            LastNum:=Num;
          end;
          
      Checknum:=CheckNum+1;
      CheckedNum[CheckNum]:=Num;
      CheckedSum[CheckNum]:=C2;    
    end;
    
  NumUsed:='F';
  Num:=Num+1;
  Sum:=0;
  Sum2:=0;
  C:=0;
  C2:=0;
  end;

Readln;        
end.
```

Output:

> ```
> 1)     220     284
> 2)    1184    1210
> 3)    2620    2924
> 4)    5020    5564
> 5)    6232    6368
> 6)   10744   10856
> 7)   12285   14595
> 8)   17296   18416
> 9)   63020   76084
> 10)   66928   66992
> 11)   67095   71145
> 12)   69615   87633
> 13)   79750   88730
> 14)  100485  124155
> 15)  122265  139815
> 16)  122368  123152
> 17)  141664  153176
> 18)  142310  168730
> 19)  171856  176336
> 20)  176272  180848
> 21)  176336  171856
> ```
>
> *176336 repeats on the preceding line, when 176336 already appeared on the right column two lines before.
>
> ```
> 22)  180848  176272
> 23)  185368  203432
> 24)  196724  202444
> ```

Comment: Consider rewriting the code in a more logical fashion, as well. This is almost impenetrable.

Comment: It appears [*friendly numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number "Friendly number (Wikipedia)") is a very different concept. The proper English term for what you are talking about here seems to be [*amicable numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers "Amicable numbers (Wikipedia)").

Comment: I was prompted with this for a programming class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between what you are storing into the arrays and what you are displaying on the screen. You are storing *every* pair, but displaying (or, at least, trying to display) only unique ones. And you are enumerating the displayed pairs differently from those stored. Adding to that is the fact that, when checking whether a number has already been encountered (and displayed, apparently), you are searching only the first 35 elements of your arrays.

Now, if you decided to display *all* the pairs that your program discovers, i.e. to see what is being stored into the arrays and under which indices, you could see the following:

```
1)     220     284
2)     284     220
3)     496     496
4)    1184    1210
5)    1210    1184
6)    2620    2924
7)    2924    2620
8)    5020    5564
9)    5564    5020
10)    6232    6368
11)    6368    6232
12)    8128    8128
13)   10744   10856
14)   10856   10744
15)   12285   14595
16)   14595   12285
17)   17296   18416
18)   18416   17296
19)   63020   76084
20)   66928   66992
21)   66992   66928
22)   67095   71145
23)   69615   87633
24)   71145   67095
25)   76084   63020
26)   79750   88730
27)   87633   69615
28)   88730   79750
29)  100485  124155
30)  122265  139815
31)  122368  123152
32)  123152  122368
33)  124155  100485
34)  139815  122265
35)  141664  153176
36)  142310  168730
37)  153176  141664
38)  168730  142310
39)  171856  176336  <<<
40)  176272  180848
41)  176336  171856
42)  180848  176272
43)  185368  203432
44)  196724  202444
...
```

Note when 176336 is first encountered: in the pair #39. Now you see why your program seems to disregard it when displaying the number the second time: simply because it doesn't bother to search the arrays beyond the 35th element.

On the other hand, 35 *might* be enough if you stored only what you displayed.

Comment: This worked. Thanks, I did not notice I was only going to 35 during my check. The program just needed a few other tweaks other than what you stated.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for your final list is 
`If (C2<>LastNum) and (NumUsed<>'T') and (Num<>C2) Then`

Using
`If (C2<>LastNum) and (NumUsed<>'T') and (Num<C2) Then`
should leave only one pair having the smaller number first.

The switched pairs are also in 20) and 22) and probably there are more to follow.

Haven't checked the correctness, though.